# Google Maps URL with pushpin and satellite basemap

Tags: google-maps, url

### Background Information

I can form a simple valid Google Maps URL that has a pushpin on a coordinate like so using the `query` parameter:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=47.5951518,-122.3316393
```

[image: Map with pushpin]

[Direct link](https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=47.5951518,-122.3316393)

Similarly, I can form a URL with a satellite image of the same location using the `center` and `basemap` parameters:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/@?api=1&map_action=map&center=47.5951518,-122.3316393&zoom=17&basemap=satellite
```

[image: Satellite map with no pushpin]

[Direct link](https://www.google.com/maps/@?api=1&map_action=map&center=47.5951518,-122.3316393&zoom=17&basemap=satellite)

### Desired End Result

What I'd like to have is a satellite image like in the second URL with a pushpin. The result of this can be seen by using the first URL and pressing the 'Satellite' button on the bottom left of the map. From what I can tell, the `basemap` and `query` parameters may not be used together like below, but I'd love to be proven wrong.

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=47.5951518,-122.3316393&basemap=satellite
```

Desired end result:

[image: Satellite map with pushpin]

[Direct link](https://www.google.com/maps/place/47%C2%B035'42.6%22N+122%C2%B019'53.9%22W/@47.5951518,-122.3316393,541m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d47.5951518!4d-122.3316393)

I need to be able to construct the URL with a dynamic set of coordinates. I haven't found a way to manipulate the parameters in order to accomplish this.

> Note: the final URL I included is an "unpacked" URL generated by Google Maps and not constructed by hand. I haven't found a way to manipulate it the way I want, and even if I could, I'm sure it's not the *correct* way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You are right in that this can't be done with the new Google Maps APIs. The "Search" URL scheme allows pinning but no satellite view, whilst the "Display a map" scheme allows satellite views but no pinning.

However, it *is* possible get both pinning and satellite views by using this old, no-official-documentation, scheme:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?t=k&q=loc:47.5951518+-122.3316393
```

The `t` parameter used to work with a number of different values but only two seem to currently still work:

- `t=m` - Normal map view
- `t=k` - Satellite view

---

Note that unofficial documentation for the other parameters can be found [here](https://moz.com/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters). Some of these may also still work.

Comment: Genius, thanks for this. With luck they'll keep backwards compatible and it won't just stop working one day.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think something has changed recently as I am no longer able to get a pin when t=k (satellite view).

Comment: FWIW: t=h - Hybrid view, t=p - Terrain view.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone still looking for a solution in 2022, you can use the following undocumented URL scheme:
`https://www.google.com/maps/place/{lat},{lng}/@{lat},{lng}/data=!3m1!1e3`

This is the best solution I could find that mimic the plan-limited query URL scheme:
`https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query={lat},{lon}`