# Google Maps URL with pushpin, satellite basemap and rotation

Tags: url, rotation, maps

In [Google Maps URL with pushpin and satellite basemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47038116/google-maps-url-with-pushpin-and-satellite-basemap) the pushpin and satellite basemap was solved with e.g. URL:

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?t=k&q=loc:47.5951518+-122.3316393
```

Using `?t=k=loc:...`

Is it also somehow possible to get the map rotated (called "heading: Indicates the compass heading of the camera in degrees clockwise from North. Accepted values are from -180 to 360 degrees.")

I have tried to add heading to the URL above but have not been successful, maybe it can only be used with a street view? Is there some other way to rotate the map in non-street-view by adding some parameters for this in the URL?

I have read thru https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started but have not found any help there, besides heading which seems to only be used in street view.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is:

`https://www.google.com/maps/place/47°35'42.6"N+122°19'53.9"W/@47.595152,-122.331639,1470a,35y,96.70h/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d47.595152!4d-122.331639`

where I use both the coordinates in degrees:

```
47°35'42.6"N+122°19'53.9"W
```

and in decimal (twice):

```
47.595152,-122.331639
47.595152!4d-122.331639
```

and the yaw (azimuth/heading) is regulated by `96.70h` (a value between `0` and `360`)

There may a simpler approach.